# Prove that a function is constant on a plane given a differential equation in two varibales

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Given a function 
>   $$f\colon \Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}\rightarrow \Bbb R$$ which satisfies $$x \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} -y \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = f.$$ Show the function is zero on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.

I have tried to integrate the differential equation with respect to both $y$ and $x$ but it's led me nowhere. I have also considered differentiating with respect to both y and x but no mixed partial second order derivative seems useful.

Any tips on how to proceed with the question?

Comment: Thanks for your tip! I have simplified it down to three equations, namely $x=x0 -ys$     $ y=y0+ys$      $f=f0+fs$ How should I show that $f=0 for all (x,y)$?

Answer (score 2):

Fix $r>0$ and consider $g(t)=f(r\cos t,r\sin t)$.
Then $$ \frac d{dt}g(t)=-r\sin t\cdot f_x(r\cos t,r\sin t)+r\cos t\cdot f_y(r\cos t,r\sin t)=f(r\cos t,r\sin t)=g(t).$$
This makes $g$ exponential (i.e., $g(t)=ae^t$ for some $a\in\Bbb R$) and periodic (namely $g(2\pi)=g(0)$), hence $g\equiv 0$. As this works for any $r>0$ we conclude that $f\equiv0$.